# Finding inverse tangent from sine?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, robotics

Im watching a video that goes from

$ p*sin(\phi - \theta) = 0 $

to

$ \phi - \theta = atan2(0,\pm1)$

without any intermediate steps. Could anyone explain the maths behind this? Unsure if its some trigonometric rule I'm missing.

Thanks!

Please note atan2 is the matlab inverse tangent function.

Answer (score 0):

If $ \phi - \theta = x, p*\sin x = 0 $

then please note

$$ x = atan2(0,\pm 1 )$$

means angle  $x$ radius vector tip is placed at $x=\pm 1$

$$ x= 0,\pi, 2 \pi,3 \pi ....$$

Comment: Thank you for your response! Could I ask what is meant by radius vector tip? I don't think I have heard that terminology before